# How to apply a selector style on some other selector?

Tags: html, css

I would like to apply on some selector a style which is already defined on another selector (when applicable).

I would like to do this since I have a style that is already defined in some external CSS file on some selector. And I want to replicate this style on some other selector, without copy-paste or the need to edit my CSS file if the external CSS file changes in the future (divide and conquer).

Something like this:

External CSS file:

```
table tfoot td {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ffffff), to(#cfcfcf));
}
```

My CSS file:

```
table thead td {
    getStyle(table tfoot td);
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I think your best bet is making the style block a class

Comment: You can share the style if you use JavaScript to copy it from one selector to another.

Comment: one way is to go for classes instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really do that in native CSS. You'd need to use a pre-processor like [SCSS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) and use variables.

Clarification: as Triztian pointed out in his comment you can use native CSS to do this with a reusable selector like a class, but the actual copying of a style from one selector to another isn't possible.

Comment: But if I got you guys right - then in this case I will have to change the external CSS file. Am I correct?

Comment: yes, you will need to change the external css file to use classes if you want to share css definitions across selectors.